# Django Categories Admin interface behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am confused with the django-categories admin interface:

My code:

```
# views.py                                                                 
from django.db import models
from categories.models import CategoryBase

class Category(CategoryBase):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

# admin.py                                                                 
from django.contrib import admin
from ktv.models import Article, Category

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Article)
```

[image: django-categories admin interface]

My questions are:

1. Why am I seeing two `categories` group? Do I need all of them?
2. I have created some categories (don't remember through which group), they are visible from the top `Categories->Categories` group, but not from the bottom `Ktv->Categorys`, why?
3. Out of curiosity, why `Categories` then `Categorys`? 
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. django-categories is registering the first one in its `admin.py`, and you are registering the second one in your `admin.py`.

   You only need both if you are planning to use both the provided `Category` model and your own custom model derived from `CategoryBase`. If you just need the former, don't define your own `Category` model. If you just need the latter, install only the `categories.editor` app, not the `categories` app. (See the [documentation](https://django-categories.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).)

   In either case, I would rename your own `Category` to something else to avoid this confusion.
2. You're talking about two different models that happen to share the same name. They don't have anything to do with each other.
3. Because they defined a [plural name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name_plural) and you didn't.